# Set Column Data Type

Tags: python, pandas, parsing

How do I set the column data type BEFORE importing?

```
df = pd.read_fwf(filepath_or_buffer = ...,
                 names = ...,
                 colspecs = ...)
```

Currently, values for columns in the fixed-width format file that are in the form `01` are being converted into a float `1.00000`.

So when I convert back to a string, it becomes `1` instead of `01`.

Comment: You should be able to pass the argument `dtype={'name_of_col': 'str'}`

Comment: Strangely enough the newest version of the Pandas docs seems to omit a bunch of arguments for `read_fwf_()`, you can try using the information [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.read_fwf.html).

Comment: @ALollz  But according to docs, `Only a single dtype is allowed.` My dataframe has multiple columns with different types.

Comment: @AMC  I looked through it, I couldn't find any way to pre-set data types for each column specified. That's weird as it should be a basic feature.

Comment: @NoName Command-F "dtype" finds _dtype : Type name or dict of column -> type, default None
Data type for data or columns. E.g. {‘a’: np.float64, ‘b’: np.int32} Use str or object to preserve and not interpret dtype. If converters are specified, they will be applied INSTEAD of dtype conversion._

Comment: You can either pass a sinlge scalar `dtype='str'` to keep everything a string, or you can provide a dictionary, which will parse those columns as you've specified, and then I believe it will use the internals to infer dtypes of whatever you haven't specified.

Comment: @ALollz  And the key of the dictionary is the column names I specified in the `names = ...` argument?

Comment: Yes, it should be.